# ASP.NET Web App Default Theme menu rendering

Tags: asp.net, css

I've developing an ASP.NET 4.0 Web App, using the default theme, while my designer don't start a new one.

Now I've faced a problem. Yesterday everything is all right, but today the menu don't render like suposed, render like a normal ul list.

I've try to change the local port for Visual Studio Development Server and the problem stil.

If a create a new project everything goes fine, and the menu was rendered like supose!

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you place some output and code that needed to be generated?

Comment: The "normal" in template are like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/rightmenu.png/
The wrong: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/84/wrongmenu.png/

Do you want the html code?

Comment: You need to post the code you are using so we can tell if you are using incorrect/missing .net properties.